# use of replication_factor in cassandra

Tags: cassandra, replication-factor

I have this code:

```
CREATE KEYSPACE “KeySpace Name”
WITH replication = {'class': ‘Strategy name’, 'replication_factor' : ‘No.Of  replicas’}
```

What is the use of  '**replication_factor**' in the above  Cassandra query?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The replication factor is an integer, it determines how many time your data is replicated across your cluster. You usually want to replicate your data to achieve high availability. Of course, it comes at the cost of extra storage. Replication factor (RF) of 3 is by far the most common value. This works if you have at least 3 nodes in your cluster.

Comment: Thank you very much for quick reply and solving my doubt @Christophe Schmitz